# Vim Solarized Theme black space

Tags: vim

I have the solarized theme working in a terminal vim session. It looks great at first until you move off page and black space appears. If you then scroll back up the black space is also in the originally colored areas... The colors do not change if you use page up page down, only j,k

[image: original load of vim .vimrc file]

What the error looks like:

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the Background Color Erase of the terminal
fixed by adding the line

`set t_ut=`

see for further details
[further details](http://sunaku.github.io/vim-256color-bce.html)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have the the `solarized dark` theme working in your terminal Vim session. I can tell because your background is black/dark gray. The `solarized dark` background is [dark blueish](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/img/screen-html-dark.png).

To get the `solarized` colorscheme to work properly within your terminal emulator you have to [change the color settings of your terminal emulator](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) to `solarized`.

How to do so depends on which kind of terminal emulator you use. With gnome-terminal, you can set the colors to `solarized` this way: `Edit - Profile Preferences - Colors - Palette - Builtin schemes: solarized`. For other terminal emulator use Google to figure out how to change the terminal emulator color.

Note that this of course also changes the colors displayed in your normal shell - but this is necessary and [advised](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if it is even possible with Bitvise. A quick google search showed no results. There are other Windows SSH clients which support solarized colorscheme, e.g. PuTTY.